# ¿Cómo hacer un marco de datos desde un beautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Dentro de un objeto soup saqué todo el texto de la división `inner_left2` donde hay artículos y fechas y quiero sacar todos los artículos y las fechas en una dataframe. Parece que los artículos y las fechas se encuentran en `span` tag. Entonces hice :

```
page = requests.get('https://www.abcbourse.com/marches/news_valeur.aspx?p=1&s=DJIAx')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
actualites_ws = soup.find(class_='inner_left2')
spans_date_article = actualites_ws.find_all('span', class_="lh24")
```

Esto da lo siguiente :

```
[<span class="lh24">
<span class="mr5">16/01/19 22:30</span>
<a href="wall-street-finit-en-hausse-goldman-sachs-et-bank-of-america-a-l-honneur_459575_DJIAx.aspx">Wall Street finit en hausse, Goldman Sachs et Bank of America à l'honneur</a> (AFP)<br/>
</span>, <span class="lh24">
<span class="mr5">16/01/19 16:14</span>
<a href="wall-street-soutenue-par-les-resultats-de-banques-ouvre-en-hausse_459537_DJIAx.aspx">Wall Street, soutenue par les résultats de banques, ouvre en hausse</a> (AFP)<br/>
</span>, <span class="lh24">
<span class="mr5">16/01/19 14:36</span>
<a href="usa-baisse-de-1-des-prix-a-l-import-en-decembre_459525_DJIAx.aspx">Baisse de 1% des prix à l'import en décembre</a> (CF)<br/>
</span>, <span class="lh24">
<span class="mr5">15/01/19 22:30</span>
<a href="wall-street-finit-en-hausse-profite-de-la-chine-et-de-netflix_459446_DJIAx.aspx">Wall Street finit en hausse, profite de la Chine et de Netflix</a> (AFP)<br/>
</span>,
...
```

Pero cuando intente transformarlo en una dataframe, no funciona:

```
>>>df = pd.read_html(articles_list)
TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'ResultSet'
```

El resultado esperado esta :

```
            articles
2007-01-01  What Sticks from '06. Somalia Orders Islamist...
2007-01-02  Heart Health: Vitamin Does Not Prevent Death ...
2007-01-03  Google Answer to Filling Jobs Is an Algorithm...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema que estás teniendo es porque la función [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) lee el `html` de la página y busca elementos [`table`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). Pero la web que indicas tiene una table formada con un formato distinto.

Como bien has "scrapeado" con `bs4`, cada fila se forma así:

```
<span class="lh24">
    <span class="mr5">16/01/19 22:30</span>
    <a href="wall-street-finit-en-hausse-goldman-sachs-et-bank-of-america-a-l-honneur_459575_DJIAx.aspx">Wall Street finit en hausse, Goldman Sachs et Bank of America à l'honneur</a>&nbsp;(AFP)<br>
</span>
```

**Entonces tienes varias opciones:**

- Formar el DataFrame a mano.
- Montar una `table` con los datos, y pasárselo al `read_html`.

**Te pongo un ejemplo de la primera opción:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://www.abcbourse.com/marches/news_valeur.aspx?p=1&s=DJIAx')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
actualites_ws = soup.find(class_='inner_left2')
spans_date_article = actualites_ws.find_all('span', class_="lh24")

# Variable para crear DataFrame
data = {'date': [], 'name': []}
for article in spans_date_article:
    data['name'].append(article.find('a').text)
    data['date'].append(article.find('span', class_="mr5").text)

print(pd.DataFrame(data=data))
```

**Salida del programa:**

```
              date                                               name
0   16/01/19 22:30  Wall Street finit en hausse, Goldman Sachs et ...
1   16/01/19 16:14  Wall Street, soutenue par les résultats de ban...
2   16/01/19 14:36       Baisse de 1% des prix à l'import en décembre
```